# Ear pain when using on-ear headphones

Tags: recording, physiology

I have a set of Bowers and Wilkins P3 headphones that I've had for about 2 months now and they are pretty comfortable but sometimes I get a very sharp pain in my right ear. I have experimented and found that the pain will happen even if there is no music playing, so it isn't an issue of volume.

Is this a common issue with on-ear headphones? Is there something I can do to alleviate the pain, or should I look into a different style of headphones?

Comment: The original question was ripe for closure, but I have had a similar problem with over-ear headphones so I've edited to bring it on-topic

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly where your pain is located and how much these headphones apply pressure on your ears, but I used to experience some pain (in the pinna) due to the pressure of my headphones when I wore them for too long.

Now I'm used to it and don't feel any pain at all even after an entire day wearing them.

Comment: It starts along the auricle and radiates down inside the ear canal. The helix also tends to be quite painful. So if it's a pressure thing my ears will eventually just toughen up? I assumed that was the case as I've been using in-ear buds for maybe 10 years and this is my first ever on-ear set.

Comment: The most painful area in my case was the helix, but I didn't feel any pain inside the canal.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_ear

Comment: @AaronLang, please do edit the current question with some specifics about where the pain is occuring